# Why does the "lotteries" tag exist?

Tags: discussion, tag-management

> Why does [lotteries](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lotteries) exist?

It doesn't help the answerer know anything about the question. You can't really be an expert in math questions about lotteries. It doesn't even have a tag description.

Note: Upvote this post to support removing the tag, downvote to support keeping the tag.

Comment: It should be done away with.

Comment: You can try to check also with [arjafi's query](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/25038/can-you-tell-who-created-a-tag/25041#25041), but it seems that the tag was created [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/8/31). (At least, that was when I noticed it.)

Comment: This post is now deleted, so the link is mainly for 10k+ users: [Do we need an “urn” tag for probability questions about extracting balls from urns?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/25401). It was about suggestion to create (urns) tag and the discussion in the comments also mention some other tags. The tags (coins) and (coin-flipping) existed in the post. The tags ([tag:dice]) and ([tag:card-games]) exists currently. I am not saying that all of them are on the same level, but I would say that are - to some extent - of similar nature.

Comment: It exists because I created it, because there are many questions on MSE pertaining to lotteries, and because a tag is more convenient than the search engine.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Aren't tags supposed to help users find questions that the are suited to answering?

Comment: @suomynonA Questions? Why not find answers that are worth reading?

Comment: "You can't really be an expert in math questions about lotteries" a significant part of my day job is being such an expert.

Comment: You can be an expert at calculating odds and such, but you can't really be an expert on questions involving lotteries. You can be an expert on topics that may involve lotteries, such as probability or combinatorics

Comment: @suomynonA there is lottery specific terminology and problems such as calculating returns from bridgehead lottery systems and the like.  See The Mathematics of Lottery: Odds, Combinations, Systems By Catalin Barboianu for a coverage of the subject.